# isn't computing hash value by polynomial rolling for string O(n), where n is the string size?

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, hash

Just read about string hashing and polynomial hash function to calculate it.
It looks like to me as if the time complexity of computing hash(string) is O(N) where 'N' is the string size

```
long long compute_hash(string const& s) {
 const int p = 31;
 const int m = 1e9 + 9;
 long long hash_value = 0;
 long long p_pow = 1;
 for (char c : s) {
     hash_value = (hash_value + (c - 'a' + 1) * p_pow) % m;
     p_pow = (p_pow * p) % m;
 }
 return hash_value;
}
```

Where the hash value of string 'S' can be computed as `S[0] + S[1].P + S[2].P.P + . . . S[N - 1].P^(N - 1)`

And if the computation is O(N) then isn't hashing N strings is O(N^2)?

Comment: It is not because you have *n* strings, that these strings have length *n*, the time complexity of adding *n* strings with length *k* is indeed *O(n k)*.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: given you insert *n* strings with length *n*, the reasoning is correct, but the "scenario" that the length of the strings is determined by the number of strings to hash, is a bit *strange*.

> And if the computation is O(N) then isn't hashing N strings is O(N<sup>2</sup>)?

Well given the length of the strings scales with the number of strings, then, for the given hashing algorithm, this will indeed result in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. But typically there is no correlation between the length of a string, and the number of strings to hash.

If the strings have an average length of *k*, and there are *n* strings, then this is an ***O(n×k)*** algorithm. You are thus correct that the "size" of the objects can have an impact on the performance, given of course the hashing algorithm scales with the size of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hashing N strings of length N is an O(N²) process. (Though in practice, you very very rarely meet such a coincidental case.)